# Wait until image loads before showing

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I have a bunch of images on a page and for the purpose of this site the client wants the images not to load in the normal way they do slowly appearing, rendering line by line.

Rather what we're looking to do is wait until the image is loaded, and while the image is loading, in its place to show a little loading gif. As each image is loaded, it fades in.

What I've done for this so far is this:

```
$('img').each(function(){

    $(this).load(function(){

        $(this).fadeIn();

    });    

});
```

Works as expected. But I'd like to take it to the next level.

Lets assume there is 20 images on this page, but only 1 or 2 are visible on the page at one time. I would then like the other 18 to not be bothered loading unless the browser scrolls down to make these apparent.

I understand there are plugins to do this - like lazyload - but I have not had good results with these plugins.

How can I do a check with jquery or javascript to see if the image is in the current viewport?

1. my each() function would only initially loop through visible images
2. as images come into view, they would load, then fadein.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a plugin like **[InView](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview)**.

However, you'd probably have to attach the event to the `img`'s containers and only load the images once the containers are "in view".

**Edit**

[Here's an example](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview#live-events) of how to use the plugin to 'lazily load' images.

```
// Assuming that all images have set the 'data-src' attribute
// instead of the 'src' attribute
$("img[data-src]").live("inview", function() {

    // Load the image
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));

    // Remove it from the set of matching elements in order to avoid
    // the handler from re-executing
    $(this).removeAttr("data-src");

});
```

Note: `live()` is being replaced by `on()` and `delegate()`, you should probably use one of those instead.

Comment: That looks promising. I will look into it now.

Answer (score -2):

Do something like this

```
<div id='loder'><img src="loder.gif"></div>

<div id='images' style="display:none;">
<img src='image1.jpg'>
<img src='image2.jpg'>
<img src='image3.jpg'>
<img src='image4.jpg'>
<img src='image5.jpg'>
</div>
```

Then on document ready hide the loder div and show the images div.

```
$(function(){
$("#loder").hide();
$("#images").show();
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't achieve any of the things I'm trying to do. And the thing you're trying to solve for me I've already accomplished with my code in the question.